# How do I get my regular expression to work with 3 numbers or more when two numbers are the same

Tags: regex

The below regular expression works with 012, 201, 102, etc. I am trying to change the regular expression so that it matches 002, 200, 020O from a 4 digit number. I tried varies methods, but the regular expression is matching other patterns. Can someone give me some direction on how to resolve this issue. Thank you.

Working:

```
RegEx012 = re.compile(r'\b(?=[1-9]*0)(?=[02-9]*1)(?=[013-9]*2)\d+\b')
```

Not Working:

```
RegEx002 = re.compile(r'\b(?=[1-9]*0)(?=[1-9]*0)(?=[013-9]*2)\d+\b')
```

Results:

0250(good)

0260(good)

2052(bad)

2062(bad)

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what exact pattern are correct and why? You say you need 002, 200, 020 etc but then later you mention 0250 and the likes. Must there simply be two zeros?

Comment: @JvdV asked you questions, indicating that the question is not clear. You have since edited the question and it is still not clear. I have downvoted and voted to close the question, not just because it is not clear (I am hoping you will fix it), but because you have not answered JvdV's legitimate questions. If you both clarify the question and respond to JvdV I will remove my downvote and (if I can) my vote to close.

Comment: IIUC, it seems it would be required to match up to `n!` alternations. for `{0,1,2}`: `\b\d*(?:0\d*1\d*2|0\d*2\d*1|1\d*0\d*2|1\d*2\d*0|2\d*0\d*1|2\d*1\d*0)\d*\b`. Half of `n!` if two of the set are the same, as in `{0,0,2}`: `\b\d*(?:0\d*0\d*2|0\d*2\d*0|2\d*0\d*0)\d*\b`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match a string with 2 times a zero and at least 3 digits, you could use a positive lookahead:

```
\b(?=[1-9]*0[1-9]*0[1-9]*\b)\d{3,}\b
```

*Explanation*

- `\b` Word boundary
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right contains

  - `[1-9]*0[1-9]*0[1-9]*\b` Match 2 times a zero between optional digits 1-9
- `)` Close lookahead
- `\d{3,}` Match 3 or more digits
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cc0BW1/1)

Or the other way around, assert 3 digits and match 2 times a zero between optional digits 1-9

```
\b(?=\d{3})[1-9]*0[1-9]*0[1-9]*\b
```

To match when the third character is a 3 (Or use a character class `[03]` to match either a 0 or 3)

```
\b(?=[1-9]*0[1-9]*0[1-9]*\b)\d{2}3\d*\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/E0agQq/1)

Comment: Thank you. I need the third digit to be specific number, such as 003.  For example 003, 030, 003.

Comment: If the third digit should be a 0 or 3 `\b(?=[1-9]*0[1-9]*0[1-9]*\b)\d{2}[03]\d*\b` If it should be a 3 then `\b(?=[1-9]*0[1-9]*0[1-9]*\b)\d{2}3\d*\b`

Comment: What is needed for 4 digits? I ran the regex for 004, but it did not find 0094.

Comment: What is the rule for 004 in 0094? Should 4 be at the fourth place? Then you have to change number and the quantifier. `\b(?=[1-9]*0[1-9]*0[1-9]*\b)\d{3}4d*\b`

Comment: I am looking for the regex to match the match 004 in any order and the fourth number regardless of position be any number. Here is a list that the regex should match.   0049
0034
0401
0420
0504
0640
4007
4080
3004
9040

Comment: @rj23729 Try it like this `\b(?=[1-9]*0[1-9]*0[1-9]*\b)(?=\d{3})\d*4\d*\b`  https://regex101.com/r/K3vp8e/1

Comment: @rj23729 Did that work out?